# Validation for the data input c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I am trying to make a login window for users and admin using XML files, so my issue is how to validate that the username and pwd field if the password is incorrect, my code only validate for admin but for the user, the form shows and it gives error as well.
It will be better if I can make it up with errorProvider.

Thank you in advance.

```
 private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string file = @"../../../data/UsersDatabase.Xml";
        doc.Load(file);


            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//User"))
            {
                username = node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;
                pwd = node.SelectSingleNode("pass").InnerText;
            }

            if (username.Equals(txtusername.Text) && pwd.Equals(txtpwd.Text))
            {

                purchase fpur = new purchase();
                fpur.Show();
            }


            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//Admin"))
            {
                username = node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;
                pwd = node.SelectSingleNode("pass").InnerText;
            }

            if (username.Equals(txtusername.Text) && pwd.Equals(txtpwd.Text))
            {
                Adminpanel fadmin = new Adminpanel();

                fadmin.Show();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, username and password are incorrect",
                "Login Failed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

    }
```

Comment: What erro it gives? And plz also share the XML!

Comment: I don't mean error, I mean the else statement error. this one below
else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, username and password are incorrect",
                "Login Failed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your xml and your description, you would like to show different forms when we

input the correct userid and password.

I make the following code and it works well.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User user = new User();
        Admin admin = new Admin();
        string path = "D:\\test.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        var user1 = doc.Descendants("User");
        foreach (XElement item in user1)
        {
            if (txtUserName.Text==item.Element("id").Value&& txtPWD.Text == item.Element("pass").Value)
            {
                user.Show();
            }
        }
        var admin1= doc.Descendants("Admin");
        foreach (XElement item in admin1)
        {
            if (txtUserName.Text == item.Element("id").Value && txtPWD.Text == item.Element("pass").Value)
            {
                admin.Show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Besides, you need to use `using System.Xml.Linq;`;

The next is the tested xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Loginlist> 
<Admin>
<FirstName>Administrator</FirstName> 
<LastName>A</LastName> 
<EmailAddress>admin@ge.com</EmailAddress> 
<PhoneNumber>1</PhoneNumber> 
<id>admin</id> 
<pass>admin</pass> 
</Admin> 
<User> 
<FirstName>Ab</FirstName> 
<LastName>Mo</LastName> 
<EmailAddress>ab@ge.com</EmailAddress> 
<PhoneNumber>1</PhoneNumber> 
<id>user</id> 
<pass>user</pass> 
</User>
</Loginlist>
```

The tested result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, but if there will be more than one user and more than one admin it will not work in this way

Comment: @user3750496, I am sorry for that. Now I have modified my code and it works well based on my test. You can check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points -

1. Your code is not making differentation between the admin and the user validation - For istance -  once the user code is validated as mentioned below -

   ```
   if (username.Equals(txtusername.Text) && pwd.Equals(txtpwd.Text))
               {        
                   purchase fpur = new purchase();
                   fpur.Show();
               }
   ```

   The admin code is still running in the background and as the XML wont validate the admin 
   at that time it is giving error as you mentioned -
2. When you pass admin related XML it will only validate the admin code as it is at the end of code so admin related code is working fine.

   If you want validate both then you may have differentiate them whether the input is 
     admin or user in that way your conditional statements will run accordingly. Aso I 
     removed couple of duplicate code and the code below is one way of doing it and place this code in your btnlogin_Click event code-

   ```
               XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
               string file = @"../../../data/UsersDatabase.Xml";
               doc.Load(file);

               bool isUser = false;
               bool isAdmin = false;

               //User
               foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//User"))
               {
                   isUser = true;
                   username = node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;
                   pwd = node.SelectSingleNode("pass").InnerText;
               }
               //Admin
               foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//Admin"))
               {
                   isAdmin = true;
                   username = node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;
                   pwd = node.SelectSingleNode("pass").InnerText;
               }
               if (username.Equals(txtusername.Text) && pwd.Equals(txtpwd.Text))
               {
                   if (isAdmin)
                   {
                       Adminpanel fadmin = new Adminpanel();

                       fadmin.Show();
                   }
                   else if(isUser)
                   {
                       purchase fpur = new purchase();
                       fpur.Show();
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("Sorry, username and password are incorrect",
                   "Login Failed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
               }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I am a beginner in C# and I don't know how to use  "static void Main(string[] args)"  I want to process this code when I click the button login. I am working with Windows Form Application.
Secondly, this error is shown for txtusername.Text and txtpwd.Text and it says " An Object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'login.txtusername'  "

Comment: I have updated my answer you have to place that code in btnlogin_Click ebent handler which you already have!

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, it's working only for Admin but for users it gives me the else error statement
this is the XML data
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Loginlist>

<Admin>

  <FirstName>Administrator</FirstName>
  <LastName>A</LastName>
  <EmailAddress>admin@ge.com</EmailAddress>
  <PhoneNumber>1</PhoneNumber>
  <id>admin</id>
  <pass>admin</pass> 
  
</Admin>

<User>

  <FirstName>Ab</FirstName>
  <LastName>Mo</LastName>
  <EmailAddress>ab@ge.com</EmailAddress>
  <PhoneNumber>1</PhoneNumber>
  <id>user</id>
  <pass>user</pass> 

</User>

Comment: Any one time either admin or user will log in? Why you have both of them in one XML?